How to draw consistent dotted line similar to default blender measure tool?
I want to draw the dotted lines similar to the default blender measure tool but the dotted line doesn't remain consistent while zooming the viewpoint.
here is the script modified from docs example
import bpy
import gpu
from random import random
from mathutils import Vector
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader


vert_out = gpu.types.GPUStageInterfaceInfo("my_interface")
vert_out.smooth("FLOAT", "v_ArcLength")

shader_info = gpu.types.GPUShaderCreateInfo()
shader_info.push_constant("MAT4", "u_ViewProjectionMatrix")
shader_info.push_constant("INT", "colors_len")
shader_info.push_constant("FLOAT", "dash_width")
shader_info.push_constant("FLOAT", "dash_factor")
shader_info.push_constant("VEC4", "color")
shader_info.push_constant("VEC4", "color2")

shader_info.vertex_in(0, "VEC3", "position")
shader_info.vertex_in(1, "FLOAT", "arcLength")

shader_info.vertex_out(vert_out)
shader_info.fragment_out(0, "VEC4", "FragColor")


shader_info.vertex_source(
    """
    void main()
    {
        v_ArcLength = arcLength;
        gl_Position = u_ViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    }
    """
)


shader_info.fragment_source(
    """
    void main()
    {
        float distance_along_line = v_ArcLength;
        /* Solid line case, simple. */
        if (dash_factor >= 1.0) {
            FragColor = color;
        }
        /* Actually dashed line... */
        else {
            float normalized_distance = fract(distance_along_line / dash_width);
            if (normalized_distance <= dash_factor) {
                FragColor = color;
            }
            else if (colors_len > 0) {
                FragColor = color2;
            }
            else {
                FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Black
            }
        }
    }
    """
)


shader = gpu.shader.create_from_info(shader_info)
del vert_out
del shader_info

coords = [Vector((1, -1, -1)), Vector((1, 1, -1)), Vector((1, -1, -1)), Vector((1, -1, 1))]

arc_lengths = [0]
for a, b in zip(coords[:-1], coords[1:]):
    arc_lengths.append(arc_lengths[-1] + (a - b).length)

batch = batch_for_shader(
    shader,
    "LINES",
    {"position": coords, "arcLength": arc_lengths},
)


def draw():
    matrix = bpy.context.region_data.perspective_matrix
    shader.uniform_float("u_ViewProjectionMatrix", matrix)
    shader.uniform_int("colors_len", 0)
    shader.uniform_float("dash_width", 0.1)
    shader.uniform_float("dash_factor", 0.5)
    shader.uniform_float("color", (1, 1, 1, 1))
    shader.uniform_float("color2", (1, 0, 0, 1))
    batch.draw(shader)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), "WINDOW", "POST_VIEW")


Draw a screen space dash line from (0, 0, 0) to (1, 1, 1)
Fixed dash size: 5 px
gap size: 5 px
colors_len = 0: use 1 color
colors_len = 1: use 2 color
If you see the gap size and dash size changing when zooming, it represents an optical illusion and is actually the same size in screen space
import bpy
import gpu
# from random import random
# from mathutils import Vector
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader


# https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/blender-v4.3-release/source/blender/gpu/shaders/infos/gpu_shader_line_dashed_uniform_color_info.hh
vert_out = gpu.types.GPUStageInterfaceInfo("my_interface")
vert_out.no_perspective("VEC2", "stipple_start")
vert_out.flat("VEC2", "stipple_pos")

shader_info = gpu.types.GPUShaderCreateInfo()
shader_info.vertex_in(0, "VEC3", "pos")

shader_info.push_constant("MAT4", "ModelMatrix")
shader_info.push_constant("MAT4", "ModelViewProjectionMatrix")
shader_info.push_constant("VEC2", "viewport_size")
shader_info.push_constant("FLOAT", "dash_width")
shader_info.push_constant("FLOAT", "udash_factor")
shader_info.push_constant("INT", "colors_len")
shader_info.push_constant("VEC4", "color")
shader_info.push_constant("VEC4", "color2")
shader_info.vertex_out(vert_out)
shader_info.fragment_out(0, "VEC4", "fragColor")

# https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/blender-v4.3-release/source/blender/gpu/shaders/gpu_shader_3D_line_dashed_uniform_color_vert.glsl
shader_info.vertex_source("""
void main()
{
  vec4 pos_4d = vec4(pos, 1.0);
  gl_Position = ModelViewProjectionMatrix * pos_4d;
  stipple_start = stipple_pos = viewport_size * 0.5 * (gl_Position.xy / gl_Position.w);
}
""")

# https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/blender-v4.3-release/source/blender/gpu/shaders/gpu_shader_2D_line_dashed_frag.glsl
shader_info.fragment_source("""
void main()
{
  float distance_along_line = distance(stipple_pos, stipple_start);
  /* Solid line case, simple. */
  if (udash_factor >= 1.0f) {
    fragColor = color;
  }
  /* Actually dashed line... */
  else {
    float normalized_distance = fract(distance_along_line / dash_width);
    if (normalized_distance <= udash_factor) {
      fragColor = color;
    }
    else if (colors_len > 0) {
      fragColor = color2;
    }
    else {
      discard;
    }
  }
}
""")

shader = gpu.shader.create_from_info(shader_info)
del vert_out
del shader_info

coords = [[0.0] * 3, [1.0] * 3]

batch = batch_for_shader(
    shader,
    "LINES",
    {"pos": coords},
)


def draw():
    region = bpy.context.region
    
    matrix = bpy.context.region_data.perspective_matrix
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("ModelViewProjectionMatrix", matrix)
    shader.uniform_float("viewport_size", (region.width, region.height))
    shader.uniform_int("colors_len", 1)
    shader.uniform_float("dash_width", 10.0)
    shader.uniform_float("udash_factor", 0.5)
    shader.uniform_float("color", (1, 1, 1, 1))
    shader.uniform_float("color2", (0, 0, 0, 1))
    batch.draw(shader)


handler = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), "WINDOW", "POST_VIEW")
#bpy.app.timers.register(
#    lambda: bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(handler, 'WINDOW'),
#    first_interval = 5)


Shader copied from Blender source code
gpu_shader_line_dashed_uniform_color_info.hh
https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/blender-v4.3-release/source/blender/gpu/shaders/infos/gpu_shader_line_dashed_uniform_color_info.hh
gpu_shader_3D_line_dashed_uniform_color_vert.glsl
https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/blender-v4.3-release/source/blender/gpu/shaders/gpu_shader_3D_line_dashed_uniform_color_vert.glsl
gpu_shader_2D_line_dashed_frag.glsl
https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/blender-v4.3-release/source/blender/gpu/shaders/gpu_shader_2D_line_dashed_frag.glsl

it works fine, but is there any smoothing/anti-aliasing option to smooth the lines?

@Karan
I don't know, even implement that on a simple edge in Blender api.
